# How to unlink imported eclipse project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I imported old eclipse project into IDEA and it went quite smoothly.

Unfortunately I see bunch of errors because of some linked sources in eclipse that I don't have on my machine. I would like to unlink eclipse project file from idea project if it is possible.

Here are screenshots of errors:
[image]
[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse project import Idea creates a content root for each found source root. If you like to unlink some roots, this can be done in Project Structure/Modules, Sources tab. You have to select the root you'd like to unlink and press <kbd>x</kbd> to remove it

Comment: Hi Elena, I've updated my question. There is nothing about source configuration for project

Comment: I see:) there are 3 possible solutions: 1. add these variables to ignored (either in Settings/Path Variables or in dialog that appears when you press 'Fix it' in error popup) 2. inspect your project files (the ones in .idea folder) for occurrences of these variables and remove them 3. define actual values for these variables

Comment: Or 4. dont import from eclipse. Import from maven structure instead?